# Start Docker Containers on logon under Windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

I've just set up a new Windows 10 development machine and so as to minimise the hassle of installs I've got various dev dependencies (Oracle, MongoDB, RabbitMQ, HAProxy, etc.) running under Docker using a docker-compose script.

I'd like to automatically start these containers on Windows logon but as yet I haven't figured out a way to do this; a simple script that executes `docker-compose up -d` in the correct directory should do it, but if it executes immediately on logon Docker hasn't yet started up so the script fails. Does anyone know how to programatically wait until docker is running?

Comment: Wouldn't it be a solution to initialize a swarm with only your dev machine as node, and then declare services with 1 replica. That way Docker will automatically maintain the availability of at least 1 container. This should also work after a reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is really easy to achieve via docker-compose using `restart`! Have changed out compose file as follows:

```
version: '2'
    services:
        rabbitmq:
            image: rabbitmq:3.6-management
            ports:
                - "5672:5672"
                - "15672:15672"
            volumes:
                - /var/lib/rabbitmq
            restart: unless-stopped
```

This extra `restart` directive means that unless the container has been explicitly stopped it will start up with docker on logon/reboot. Tested and working!

Answer (score 1):

To further elaborate on my comment i have done a little test with a webserver service, but it should work for any service, as long as you configure it the way you want it to behave.

Its quite easy to set this up using the following commands:

`docker swarm init`

Then for example a webserver

`docker service create --name webserver --publish 80:80 httpd`

Or even a database

`docker service create --replicas 1 --name database --publish 1433:1433 -e "ACCEPT_EULA=y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=test" microsoft/mssql-server-linux`

These will restart after a reboot and on fatal crashes automatically because of the requested amount of replicas (1 by default) that Docker swarm keeps alive for you.

Hopefully this can be of some help!

Comment: I'm sure this will work but I actually figured out a way to do this without introducing swarm, see other answer...